# Angular 2 Material Layout Rendering in different component

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-components, angular5

I am using Teradata Covalent layout

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/covalent-contacts-template
```

I am breaking this template into multiple components like header, footer, sidenav and main content layout but when I move a header area into header component it doesn't show on browser same like sidenav and main content. Its all messed up.

this is the actual template code

```
<td-layout>
  <td-layout-nav>
    <div td-toolbar-content layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex>
      <button mat-icon-button class="td-menu-button" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mdTooltip="Main menu">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-logo" svgIcon="assets:covalent"></mat-icon>
      <span>Contacts</span>
      <span flex></span>
      <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>apps</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>notifications</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon></button>
    </div>
    <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" style="width:257px;border-right:1px solid #ccc">
        <div flex class="mat-content bgc-grey-50">
          <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item class="active"><mat-icon matListIcon>contacts</mat-icon>Contacts</a>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>history</mat-icon>Frequently contacted</a>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>business</mat-icon>Directory</a>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>content_copy</mat-icon>Duplicates</a>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>add</mat-icon>Create label</a>
            <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>settings</mat-icon>Settings</a>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>announcement</mat-icon>Send feedback</a>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>help</mat-icon>Help</a>
            <a mat-list-item><mat-icon matListIcon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>Go to the old version</a>
          </mat-nav-list>
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <!-- ng content or router would go here -->
      <div tdMediaToggle="gt-xs" [mediaClasses]="['push-md']">
        <mat-card>
          <mat-nav-list flex>
            <ng-template let-item let-i="index" let-last="last" ngFor [ngForOf]="[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
              <a mat-list-item (click)="openDialog()">
                <img matListAvatar src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/285/{{i}}@adorable.io.png" />
                <h4 matLine class="cursor-pointer"> Firstname Lastname </h4>
                <span flex="100" class="mat-caption tc-grey-600">first.last@email.com</span>
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Star contact"><mat-icon>star_outline</mat-icon></button>
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Edit contact"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="More actions"><mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon></button>
              </a>
              <mat-divider *ngIf="!last" mat-inset></mat-divider>
            </ng-template>
          </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
    <a mat-fab color="accent" matTooltip="Add new contact" matTooltipPosition="before" class="mat-fab-bottom-right z-3 fixed fab-pad">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </a>
  </td-layout-nav>
  <td-layout-footer>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
      <span class="mat-caption">Copyright &copy; 2017 Teradata. All rights reserved</span>
    </div>
  </td-layout-footer>
</td-layout>
```

how to break this into multiple components?

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to use the angular-cli. Read up on this: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3 Then use the cli to make the necessary # of components. After, copy and paste those html code into the rightful html templates for each component. (Using the cli, it'll save you the trouble of configuring the app.module.ts

Comment: I am using the angular cli. I have already created app using it. My question is how to render the material directive after moving into different components?

Comment: You would have to import and declare all those components in the app.module.ts. Does that help?

Comment: I did but no luck. Check my this question as well

Comment: https://github.com/Teradata/covalent-quickstart/issues/95

Comment: That's really weird then... What about your selectors? For example, each component has its own selector. Are you utilizing them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160539/discussion-between-ezzzcash-and-haseeb-khan).